# Please unfreez the general chat room and participate in chat

Tags: discussion, support

The General chat room for this sub-site is frozen. Which is not a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

[The chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) has been unfrozen now. However it doesn't mean it will not get frozen again. Consistent inactivity can lead to its freezing again. So, Let's talk there frequently or at least occasionally.

The more important point to discuss is How we can keep or increase the enthusiasm among the users of this community. We can plan to discuss on particular topic once in a week or month...

Comment: Yes-and hopefully, such discussions will provoke interesting questions that we can later post...